# What can I deduce from Q(2x)=Q(x)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

**What can I deduce from this equation, $Q(2x)=Q(x)$?**

I was recently solving a question and arrived to this equation.

I am putting the question here just for reference.

**Find all polynomials $P(x)$ with real coefficients such that
$(x-8)P(2x)=8(x-1)P(x)$.**

I found out the roots of the equation by putting various values of x.

So, $P(8)=P(4)=P(2)=0$

Now, I wrote $P(x)$ in the form of $Q(x)$ that is,

$P(x)=(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)Q(x)$

Now, rewriting the equation and cancelling out the terms.

$(x-8)(2x-2)(2x-4)(2x-8)Q(2x)=8(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)Q(x)$

$Q(2x)=Q(x)$

I don't know what to deduce from this equation.

My answer may be wrong but I want to know what should I do next if I face these kinds of equations.

What I think most probably is that the only root of this equation is 0.

Comment: The only polynomials satisfying that are constants (just think about the leading term).

Comment: In fact the only continuous functions satisfying that are constants

Comment: Oh got it! I can use the identity theorem which states that if P(x)=P(x+T), the function is periodic then we know that the function is a constant function. So P(x)=c(x-2)(x-4)(x-8).

Comment: @Sten I have found out the degree of this polynomial as 4 but in the answer it is 6. Also I still don't have a polynomial with real coefficients.

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay : The $P$ you have described has degree $3$, not $4$.

Comment: At first I assumed Q(x) to have a degree of atlest one (so I don't get a constant because it won't give any real as in numeric coefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $Q(2x) = Q(x)$, you deduce that $Q(2^x)$ and $Q(-2^x)$ are periodic in $x$ with period (dividing) $1$.

For a polynomial with any roots other than $x = 0$, this is a problem since it implies that the polynomial has infinitely many roots.  From your deduced equation, 
$$  (x−8)(2x−2)(2x−4)(2x−8)Q(2x)=8(x−1)(x−2)(x−4)(x−8)Q(x)  \text{,}  $$
cancelling common factors leaves $Q(2x) = Q(x)$ and you know $Q(x)$ is a polynomial.  If $Q(x)$ has any roots (except at $x = 0$), it has infinitely many roots.  The only polynomial with infinitely many roots is the polynomial $0$.  Certainly, setting $Q(x) = 0$ makes the above equation true.  Alternatively, let $Q$ be any constant other than $0$ and the above equation is satisfied without reducing it to the triviality "$0 = 0$".  (We have two choices for $Q$: infinitely many roots or no roots, so either $Q = 0$ or $Q = c$ for any nonzero constant, $c$.  You might wonder: what about $x^2 + 1$, which has no roots?  It doesn't take any of its values infinitely many times.  Remember every value $Q$ takes, it takes infinitely many times.  Suppose $Q(1) = c$.  Then $Q(x) - c$ is a polynomial with infinitely many roots, so it is the zero polynomial and we find $Q(x) = c$ for all $x$.)

Another way to see that $Q$ must be constant if $Q$ is not everywhere zero is this.  Let $Q(1) = c$.  Then $Q$ takes the value $c$ infinitely many times: at $\dots$, $1/8$, $1/4$, $1/2$, $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $\dots$.  This means the polynomial $Q(x) -c$ has infinitely many zeroes, forcing $Q(x) - c = 0$, the zero polynomial.  Then $Q(x) = c$ is constant.

We already know, since $Q(x)$ is constant, that $P(x)$ is cubic, so the proposed solutions are impossible.  Neither of the answers you recite actually satisfy your functional  equation.
\begin{align*}
(x-8)\left(3(2x)^6 - 27(2x)^4 + 33(2x)^2 - 1 \right) &= 192 x^7-1536 x^6-432 x^5+3456 x^4+132 x^3-1056 x^2-x+8  \text{,}  \\
8(x-1)\left( 3x^6 - 27x^4 + 33 x - 1 \right) &= 24 x^7-24 x^6-216 x^5+216 x^4+264 x^3-264 x^2-8 x+8  \text{,}  \\
(x-8)\left((2x)^6 - 33(2x)^4 + 27(2x)^2 - 3 \right) &= 64 x^7-512 x^6-528 x^5+4224 x^4+108 x^3-864 x^2-3 x+24  \text{, and}  \\
8(x-1)\left(x^6 - 33x^4 + 27x^2 - 3 \right) &= 8 x^7-8 x^6-264 x^5+264 x^4+216 x^3-216 x^2-24 x+24  \text{.}
\end{align*}
It's easy enough to see that these don't even agree in their leading coefficients before multiplying them out: \begin{align*}
1 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^6 &\neq 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 3  \text{ and }  \\
1 \cdot 2^6 &\neq 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1
\end{align*}

Comment: So what does it mean?

Comment: Is there no such answer?

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay : How many polynomials do you know that have infinitely many roots?

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay : You seem to be conflating $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: You may be correct but when I looked into the examples related to this question and they were solved this way by using the identity theorem. I also encountered this problem you stated in your answer but I ignored them and took (x-2)(x-4)(x-8) as the roots. But at least it gave me a minimum degree the polynomial can have. If this is the wrong method then which one is right?

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay :  Let me rewrite the last paragraph of my answer.  Perhaps that will reduce our mismatch.

Comment: You are correct. How can we avoid this problem?

Comment: Your answer was brilliant. Thanks. The answer was incorrect as the RHS≠LHS.

Answer (score 2):

If $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and $Q(2x)=Q(x)$ as polynomials, then look at the leading coefficient on both sides: $2^n a_n = a_n$. This implies $n=0$, that is, $Q$ is constant.

Applying the same technique to the original problem, $(x-8)P(2x)=8(x-1)P(x)$, gives that $2^n a_n = 8 a_n$, and so $P$ has degree $3$.

Answer (score 0):

By induction,

$$Q(2^kx)=Q(x)$$ for all integer $k$. We can rewrite this as

$$Q(x)=Q\left(^{\lfloor\log_2x\rfloor+\{\log_2x\}}\right)=Q(2^{\{\log_2x\}})$$ and we can assign arbitrary values to $Q(x)$ for $x$ in $[1,2)$ and $(-2,-1]$.

If the function is non-constant, it has a singularity at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q(1)=Q_1$. Then for all $n$, $Q(2^n)=Q_1$ and the polynomial cannot be non-constant.